# Concatenación o unión de varias cadenas

Tags: c

Acabo de escribir mis primeras lineas de código en C y soy muy inexperto. Me estoy dando cuenta que la concatenación se lleva a cabo de forma diferente, me gustaría me ayudaran a comprender bien la concatenación.
supongamos en c# tengo:

```
int valor=10;
Console.WriteLine("tu valor es: " + valor + "amigo");
```

¿En C como se traduciría ese tipo de concatenaciones?

estaba probando con:

```
printf("tu valor es: %d", valor, "%s amigo");
```

pero no me sale la ultima cadena (amigo).

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿No has investigado nada al respecto? Lo que preguntas es algo básico de manual.

Comment: ¿ Quieres **contatenar** varias cadenas, o **mostrar** varias cadenas con `printf( )` ? Son cosas **muy** distintas.

Comment: @A.Cedano si es algo tan básico no crees que deberia haber una respuesta a ello en alguna pregunta antigua y marcarla como duplicado, y si no la hay seria genial esta pregunta canónica y en futuras ocasiones marcarlas como duplicado de esta y asi evitar responder este tipo de preguntas básicas :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc pues sí. Lo único que he echado en falta es que el OP indicase si ha investigado algo al respecto. Yo no soy programador de `C`, pero supongo que ¿habrá algún sitio con documentación oficial que explique cómo se concatenan varias cadenas? Si yo pregunto cómo se concatenan cadenas en PHP o en Java sin indicar que he leído la documentación, la pregunta podría ser candidata para cierre. A pesar de eso, la pregunta podría mejorarse y servir de motor para una buena respuesta sobre el tema.

Comment: @A.Cedano en realidad eso de cerrar una pregunta por investigación es muy relativo, un novato no sabe ni que existe ello y por ende no investigara, asi que yo preferiria dejar esa pregunta abierta, responderla y si existen futuras personas que preguntan lo mismo con o sin investigación las marcaria como duplicado a esta, asi tendriamos una respuesta a una pregunta básico que todo novato se enfrente y evitamos responderlas muchas veces ahorrandonos trabajo. He visto preguntas similares y siempre se cierran, y nadie responde. Asi que espero que respondan a esta explicando todos los detalles

Comment: No me parece una mala idea lo que planteas, @eyllanesc, de hecho, no he votado para cerrarla ni pienso hacerlo. Aunque sí he visto preguntas parecidas: [búsqueda de *concatenación* en la etiqueta `C`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+concatenacion) y también [búsqueda de *concatenar*  en la etiqueta `C`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+concatenar), algunas con respuestas sin aceptar, pero con puntuación favorable y con respuestas muy buenas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> estaba probando con:
>
> ```
> printf("tu valor es: %d", valor, "%s amigo");
> ```
>
> pero no me sale la ultima cadena (amigo).

No te sale porque, de acuerdo con la documentación de [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), el primer parámetro comprende la estructura básica de la cadena a mostrar y los siguientes parámetros se usan para personalizar la cadena en cuestión:

```
printf("tu valor es: %d amigo", valor);
```

Y esto es independiente de cuántas variables vayan a incorporarse a la cadena final:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;
c = a + b;
printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,c);
```

Si por alguna razón tu intención no es mostrar directamente el contenido en la pantalla sino que pretendes almacenarlo en una cadena para su posterior manipulación, tienes a tu disposición [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char resultado[200];

sprintf(resultado, "tu valor es: %d amigo", valor);

puts(resultado);
```

Comment: Excelente me sirvió de mucha ayuda tu explicación, perdón, apenas me estaba introduciendo a C. GRACIAS.